# how to remove title from phonegap alert

Tags: cordova, alert

we are using navigator.notification.confirm(alertMesg, onConfirm, '  ', buttonNamesForIos); to show confirm box using phonegap. But above function is wasting space for title as we dont to show title. How to remove title space from box.

Answer (score 0):

What platform you using ?

A simple NULL would keep it blank.

Comment: it's coming blank but wasting space. I dont want title at all.how to remove space taken by title